# jscript.net code in c# with reflection

Tags: c#, jscript

I want to run jscript.net code containing a form, some buttons with events hooked up. All that must be accomplished in c# with reflection, but i can't find a decent example with those events. Please give me some help. This is what i have till now but the last line will have errors

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine("import System.Windows.Forms;");
            sb.AppendLine("class EventTestForm extends Form");
            sb.AppendLine("{");
            sb.AppendLine(" var btn : Button;");
            sb.AppendLine("function EventTestForm()");
            sb.AppendLine("{");
            sb.AppendLine(" btn = new Button; btn.Text = \"Fire Event\";  Controls.Add(btn); btn.add_Click(ButtonEventHandler1);");
            sb.AppendLine("}");
            sb.AppendLine("function ButtonEventHandler1(sender, e : EventArgs)");
            sb.AppendLine("{");
            sb.AppendLine(" MessageBox.Show(\"Event is Fired!\");");
            sb.AppendLine("}");
            sb.AppendLine("}");

            sb.AppendLine("MessageBox.Show(\"Hello world\");");

            // Create the compiler object
            JScriptCodeProvider provider = new JScriptCodeProvider();
            ICodeCompiler compiler = provider.CreateCompiler();

            CompilerParameters options = new CompilerParameters();
            options.GenerateInMemory = true;

            options.GenerateExecutable = true;
            options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms");
            CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: what are the error messages???

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)

Comment: Thats not an error message? Is it not compiling or throwing an exception when run it?

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to run javascript in c# app you are better off using one of the js interpreters

I use jint, there is also jurassic, javascript.net, maybe others

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you just learn JavaScript? Just had a look at the `JScriptCodeProvider` class and the documentation says:

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not
>   intended to be used directly from your code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.jscript.jscriptcodeprovider.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
options.GenerateExecutable = false;
options.GenerateInMemory = true;
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.Text.dll");
options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.windows.forms.dll");
```

Use these lines